# Fast way to know if deleting an edge will disconnect a fully connected undirected graph

Tags: graphs

Given a fully connected undirected graph, is there a quick way for me to know if the graph will remain fully connected if I delete a given edge from the graph?

Quick = O(lg V) or something like that. O(V) is not quick.

Fully connected = every node is reachable from every other other node in the graph. i.e., given any two nodes in the graph, there is always a path connecting these two nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, because in the worst case you have to examine every edge (at least, under standard graph representations).

If you can preprocess the graph ($O(|V|+|E|)$ time), you can decompose it into strongly connected components and build a data structure that lets you answer this question in $O(1)$ time.

If you are repeating this many times, alternatively deleting edges and then checking whether deletion will disconnect the graph, see algorithms for [decremental graph connectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_connectivity).

See also [Incremental strongly connected components](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/96424/755), [Split-Find: maintaining dynamic graph connectivity information, under edge deletion](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/32077/755),  https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/27269/5038.